# Calling a class from a function in another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am stuck on calling a class inside a function in another class. Let's assume I have a class `A` and functions `self.B` and `c`,

```
class A
  def self.b
    //does something
  end
  def c
    //does something
  end
end
```

and another class `D`:

```
class D
  before_create :x
  def x
    //have to call the class A and its functions here
  end
end
```

Please tell me how to acheive this.

Comment: Classes cannot be "called" (except for `Callable` classes, using `.call` or equivalent methods). What you you mean by "call the class A"? If you mean you want to invoke methods `b` and `c`, `A.b` and `A.new.c` should do.

Comment: I'm not able to follow. You want a function in one class to return another class?

Comment: Are you concerned with having a class in one file call methods on a class from another file? Look up [require](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require).

Comment: By meaning call a class, I mean , to call all the methods of the class A inside another method in class D's method/function x

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include this additional information?  SO asks that the question stand on its own, without needing to read the comments.

Comment: WayneConrad - not clear dude. can you please point out what is that you need exactly?

Answer (score 5):

You an call the class methods directly on a class, and to call instance methods, you need to create an instance of the class:

```
Class D
  before_create :x

  def x
    # for a class method
    A.b

    # for an instance method
    a = A.new
    a.c 
  end
end
```

Comment: How will this work? How will class D know about class A and the existence of the methods inside it?

Comment: In Rails, all classes from the `app` and `lib` folders are preloaded, and cached in the application, so you don't have to require them. If you're using pure ruby, you need to require the class `A` file from the class `D` file.

Comment: Well not necessarily.```Rails.root/lib``` is not preloaded by default. You would have to specify this in an initializer like in application.rb like so:

```config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)```

Everything in /app is preloaded by default

Comment: @DerrickMar yep, you're right, the `lib` should be added to autoload paths.

Comment: How autoloading works in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Answer (score 2):

The A method b is simple, that is a class method and can be invoked directly from that class. So

```
class D
  def y
    A.b
  end
end
```

A method c is more interesting as that is an instance method. So you need to create an instance of class A and then invoke its method c. You can do it like this:

```
class D
  def z
    A.new.c
  end
end
```

However, you usually call instance methods because the output is determined by parameters assigned to that instance. So rather than calling  method c on a new instance of A, you'll usually want to create the new instance, configure it the required way, and then pass it to the class D method. So you need to pass the A instance to the D method. You'd usually do that like this:

```
class D
  def z(a)
    a.c
  end
end

a = A.new
d = D.new

d.z(a)
```